# How do you implement a tiled map overlay in Tk.CustomMap?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

TK.CustomMap seems to provide the ability to "overlay" tiles, but in my experience it is not working as I would expect.  How do you overly tiles on the Apple or Android map without completely replacing the existing map? 
We have a Xamarin Forms project.

The parameters that are given to are something similar to:

```
TKTileUrlOptions("http://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", 256, 256, 0, 18);
```

The TilesUrl is defined as follows:

```
        public string TilesUrl { get;  set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new instance of <see cref="TKTileUrlOptions"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tileWidth">Width of a tile image</param>
    /// <param name="tileHeight">Height of a tile image</param>
    /// <param name="tilesUrl">The url for custom map tiles. 
    /// <note type="note">Url must specify 3 placeholders({0}, {1}, {2}) which are used for providing x, y and zoom.</note>
    /// <param name="minZoomLevel">The minimum zoom level supported by the tiles</param>
    /// <param name="maxZoomLevel">The maximum zoom level supported by the tiles</param>
    /// </param>
```

It would be my impression that the typical Apple or Android map should be shown for the zoom levels not specified. For example, if I specify the minZoomLevel is 10, the native map should be shown until I zoom into level 10, for example.

Then underlying code in TKCustomMapRenderer.cs is using MKTileOverlay. My experience prior with MKTileOverlay would lead me to believe this is the correct implementation. Would there be some configuration item in this code that I need to set to show both the native map and the tiles that I am rendering as an overlay.

I have seen this question on the repo Issues, and it would effectively answer my question as well.
https://github.com/TorbenK/TK.CustomMap/issues/328

My current experience shows that on an Apple device, the device's map display is gray until I reach the tiles that I am serving. Then, the tiles show up as expected. If TK.Custom map's overlay is removed, the apple map shows up.

On the Android device, the google map is shown without any tile overlay or replacement. (it seems to ignore the configuration or layer.)

Any direction or thoughts would be appreciated.